# jQuery gets the width of an element

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to add corners to some elements in IE8, which I cannot do with CSS3. The method I take is using jQuery.corner library and wrap my elements with a div and then round that div with jQuery.corner. I found I need to resize the width of the wrapping div otherwise I got a bullet-like button, with round corners only on the left side. I have code like below, which works fine in some magnification but shows additional bar on the right side in either lower or higher magnifications. That is, sometimes the div does take the width of the element to be wrapped as I want, but sometimes it takes some number smaller than that. What should I do to improve the code?
Note the 10 is the left and right padding of the element I want to wrap.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery(".tranCoreButton").each(function(index) {
        var className = 'allRoundCorners' + index;
        var buttonWidth = jQuery(this).width() + 10;
        jQuery(this).wrap("<div class=" + className + "></div>");
        jQuery("." + className).width(buttonWidth);
        jQuery("." + className).corner("round 10px");
        jQuery("." + className).css("display", "inline-block");
    });
});
```

Comment: No need for the extra "className", you can give the style to the element before doing the wrapping

Comment: Not a direct answer, but have you tried http://css3pie.com?

Comment: I tried pie but some weird results too. Gave up soon.

Comment: @koala_dev I have several elements with that class name so I need index to distinguish them. They have different width.

Comment: @dunfa sorry I'm not following, you have other elements in your markup with classes `allRoundCornersX`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the *sane* box-model in your CSS? Maybe this helps with issues with borders and padding...

```
.tranCoreButton {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```